# cakephp unix login and execute commands

Tags: cakephp, unix, command

Over the last months I’ve built a full cakephp app for my company to handle workflow, attendance, etc.in a unix environment.

Aside from that app, many people login directly to a unix prompt to execute a variety of unix commands, ls, rm, etc.

I need to add to my cakephp app an interface that allows to login to the unix server and execute a command (user will pick from a list of commands).

For any command executed, we’d need to display the command results.

As I mentioned, I’m pretty familiar with cakephp overall, but I don’t know where to start building this part of my app, namely if there is any magic stuff for a)login in to the unix server, b)execute a command, and c)displaying the outcome.

Can you help?

Thank you so much.

Carlos

Comment: I think [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @noslone; I've used the console for an automated task; will look into it again with the unix login in mind and see how it fits.